# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2\over (e^{x}-x^2)^2}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(2n)!\over (n+1)^{2n+1}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2\over (e^{x}-x^2)^2}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(2n)!\over (n+1)^{2n+1}}$$

Applying partial fractions

$x^2=A(e^x-x^2)+B$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x\over (e^x-x^2)^2}-{1\over e^x-x^2}dx$$

Let

$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}{1\over e^x-x^2}dx$$

Applying partial fractions

$1=A(e^x-x)+B(e^x+x)$

$$J={1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\over e^x+x}+{e^{-x}\over e^x-x}dx={1\over 2}(A+B)$$ respectively.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-nx}={1\over e^x-x}$$

Let us concentrate only on B for the moment

$${1\over 2}B={1\over 2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x(n+1)}dx={1\over 2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-2}e^{-xn}dx$$

We can apply Laplace transform

$$B=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(n-2)!\over n^{n-1}}$$

The method I am doing right now seem lengthy, so I don't think this is right approach to tackle this problem. Can someone show me another way to tackle this problem?

Comment: partial fractions defined for polynomial!

Comment: decomposition of fractions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2}{(e^x-x^2)^2}= \frac{x^2 e^{-2x}}{(1-x^2 e^{-x})^2}=x^2e^{-2x}\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\left(x^2 e^{-x}\right)^n $$
hence:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{(e^x-x^2)^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n+2}e^{-(n+2)x}\,dx $$
and the last integral is straightforward to compute in terms of the $\Gamma$ function through the substitution $x=\frac{y}{n+2}$, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}y^{2n+2}e^{-y}\,dy = \Gamma(2n+3) = (2n+2)!.$$

Comment: you could detail it, if the OP never saw it : $\int_0^\infty x^{k-1} e^{-nx} dx = \int_0^\infty (y/n)^{k-1} e^{-y} d(y/n) = n^{-k}  \int_0^\infty y^{k-1} e^{-y} dy = n^{-k} \Gamma(k) = n^{-k} (k-1)!$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
 I = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{x^2 }}{{\left( {e^x  + x^2 } \right)^2 }}dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{x^2 e^{ - 2x} }}{{\left( {1 + x^2 e^{ -  x} } \right)^2 }}dx}  
\end{align}
Using the geometric series we have $$ \frac{1}{{1 - x}} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {x^n }  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{{\left( {1 - x} \right)^2 }} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {nx^{n - 1} }  $$
Substituting 
\begin{align}
 I = \int_0^\infty  {x^2 e^{ - 2x}  \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(-1)^{n-1}n\left( {x^2 e^{ -  x} } \right)^{n - 1} } dx}  \\ 
  = \int_0^\infty  {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n} e^{ -  (n+1)x} } dx}  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(-1)^{n-1}n\int_0^\infty  {x^{2n} e^{ -  (n+1)x} dx} } \,\, \\ 
 \end{align}
which is the gamma function

Comment: Error in the second line I'm pretty sure. It shouldn't be an exponent of $-2x$ but just $-x$.

Comment: yes thank you ...